# Comparsion strange behavior 0 == 'one'

Tags: php

I just found out strange behavior of PHP if clause

```
var_dump((bool)0);
var_dump((bool)"one");
var_dump(0 == "one");
```

it prints

```
bool(false) bool(true) bool(true)
```

documentation say that "expression is evaluated to its Boolean value" so a boolean value of `0` is `false` and `"one"` is `true` so the result of `0 == "one"` should be `false` but it's `true` instead.

Can someone explain it?

Comment: PHP `==` seems almost worthless. This seems relevant: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: "Is this php behaviour explained somewhere in manual? (strings with zeroes comparison) " this is not the same '0' and '0000' both are converted to 0 that's obvious

Comment: "Is this php behaviour explained somewhere in manual? (strings with zeroes comparison)" is also not the same because it will be converted to 0 cause it'll convert first number to int. It's not the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"one"` is converted to integer `0` since you do comparsion with integer `0`

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.

Check here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Correct. See http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php ('
loose comparisons with ==' table) for the boolean translation of "one"

Comment: Thanks I couldn't find proper thread to explain it